# Styling <select> tag for iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css

When a `<select>` tag is used in a HTML page, is there a way to style the text size in 
the scroll wheel that shows on the iPhone?

Comment: Kieran and Pat Fowler, your answers look good. I didn't know which answer, if any, to award the bounty to. I would really like to have something that works on desktop browsers, which neither the cubiq thing nor Mobiscroll do. For now, I am using this jQuery plugin (http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/) but I am keeping my eyes open in case something better comes up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you can style the wheel that shows up on the iPhone directly. In fact, even modifying it in browsers has weird support. For example, http://jsbin.com/obake3 doesn't work at all in Chrome, only modifies the actual drop down in Safari and stretches the graphic in a very ugly way in Firefox.

Comment: It was within the wheel that I was asking about and not on the page itself.  I would like to control font-size, color and font-family.

Answer (score 9):

There is this alternative.

http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch

It uses javascript to put the elements on the page.. I used it for a web/ iphone app and it worked really well. There would be custom styling if you wanted to change the default text sizes and you could also load in custom images..

Comment: Amazing. Some developers are really willing to go the extra mile to improve the user experience of iOS web apps.

Comment: what i find amazing is that there are people out there kicking ass and taking names putting these scripts out there for free.

Comment: this answer is 8 years old and may no longer be relevant.

Answer (score 5):

We investigated and couldn't find any reliable way of altering the display so we looked into different libraries. We're having good luck with the [Mobiscroll library for jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/). It is a more up to date project than the cubiq project referred to in other responses.

> The control is themable. You can easily change the appearance of if in CSS. It also comes with pre-defined, nice looking color schemes.

We chose it because it works across devices allowing for a more consistent look & feel.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Sitepoint Ref](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/select)

> The select renders slightly differently depending on the browser and operating system in use, and is well known as a troublesome HTML element to style with CSS (because the display is inherited from the operating system, rather than provided by the browser)